# C# Socket.BeginReceive/EndReceive

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, beginreceive

In what order is the Socket.BeginReceive/EndReceive functions called?

For instance, I call **BeginReceive** twice, once to get the message length and the second time to get the message itself. Now the scenario is like that, for every message I send, I start waiting for its completion (actually acknowledgment of the message sent, also I wait for the action's completion after receiving the acknowledgment), so I call **BeginReceive** with each **BeginSend**, but in each **BeginReceive**'s callback, I check if I'm receiving the length or the message. If I'm receiving the message and have received it completely, then I call another **BeginReceive** to receive the completion of the action. Now this is where things get out of sync. Because one of my receive callback is receiving bytes which it interprets as the length of them message when in fact it is the message itself.

Now how do I resolve it?

**EDIT:** This is a C#.NET question :)

Here is the code, basically it is too big, sorry for that

```
public void Send(string message)
{
    try
    {
        bytesSent = 0;

        writeDataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        writeDataBuffer = WrapMessage(writeDataBuffer);
        messageSendSize = writeDataBuffer.Length;

        clientSocket.BeginSend(writeDataBuffer, bytesSent, messageSendSize, SocketFlags.None,
                            new AsyncCallback(SendComplete), clientSocket);
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(socketException.Message);
    }
}

public void WaitForData()
{
    try
    {
        if (!messageLengthReceived)
        {
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(receiveDataBuffer, bytesReceived, MESSAGE_LENGTH_SIZE - bytesReceived,
                                    SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveComplete), clientSocket);
        }
}

public void Send(string message)
{
    try
    {
        bytesSent = 0;

        writeDataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        writeDataBuffer = WrapMessage(writeDataBuffer);
        messageSendSize = writeDataBuffer.Length;

        clientSocket.BeginSend(writeDataBuffer, bytesSent, messageSendSize, SocketFlags.None,
                            new AsyncCallback(SendComplete), clientSocket);
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(socketException.Message);
    }
}

public void WaitForData()
{
    try
    {
        if (! messageLengthReceived)
        {
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(receiveDataBuffer, bytesReceived, MESSAGE_LENGTH_SIZE - bytesReceived,
                                    SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveComplete), clientSocket);
        }
        else 
        {
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(receiveDataBuffer, bytesReceived, messageLength - bytesReceived,
                                    SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveComplete), clientSocket);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(socketException.Message);
    }
}

public void RecieveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = result.AsyncState as Socket;
        bytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(result);

        if (! messageLengthReceived)
        {
            if (bytesReceived != MESSAGE_LENGTH_SIZE)
            {
                WaitForData();
                return;
            }

            // unwrap message length
            int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(receiveDataBuffer, 0);
            length = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(length);

            messageLength = length;
            messageLengthReceived = true;

            bytesReceived = 0;

            // now wait for getting the message itself
            WaitForData();
        }
        else
        {
            if (bytesReceived != messageLength)
            {
                WaitForData();
            }
            else
            {
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveDataBuffer);

                MessageBox.Show(message);

                bytesReceived = 0;
                messageLengthReceived = false;

                // clear buffer
                receiveDataBuffer = new byte[AsyncClient.BUFFER_SIZE];

                WaitForData();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(socketException.Message);
    }

}

public void SendComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = result.AsyncState as Socket;
        bytesSent = socket.EndSend(result);

        if (bytesSent != messageSendSize)
        {
            messageSendSize -= bytesSent;

            socket.BeginSend(writeDataBuffer, bytesSent, messageSendSize, SocketFlags.None,
                            new AsyncCallback(SendComplete), clientSocket);
            return;
        }

        // wait for data
        messageLengthReceived = false;
        bytesReceived = 0;

        WaitForData();
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(socketException.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code/data samples?

Comment: The main issue seems to be (MESSAGE_LENGTH_SIZE - bytesReceived) which will work fine the first time - but after that will not be the correct message length size because bytesReceived is no longer 0. Its a bit ugly to be using globals to pass this stuff around when there is a state object for that sort of thing.

Comment: The problem is not with that, I have debugged many times and the problem comes out that, I call BeginReceive three times, two for receiving length and one for message, but it is called in the order that, first the callbacks for receiving the lengths are called and then the message, but then the message is broken. So I only need to know the order in which the callbacks are called.

Comment: Could you accomplish this? I am having same problem. its been long time since you asked this question. I suppose you found a solution. can you give me some help? thanks

Answer (score 22):

The order in time should be:

1. `BeginReceive` for message length
2. `EndReceive` for the completion of #1
3. `BeginReceive` for the message body
4. `EndReceive` for the completion of #3

E.g. not using callbacks you could have:

```
var sync = socket.BeginReceive(....);
sync.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
var res = socket.EndReceive(sync);
sync = socket.BeginReceive(....);
sync.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
var res2 = socket.EndReceive(sync);
```

But then, you would be better just using `Receive`!

I think you might find it easier to use separate handlers for the two different receives:

```
... Start(....) {
    sync = socket.BeginReceive(.... MessageLengthReceived, null);
}

private void MessageLengthReceived(IAsyncResult sync) {
  var len = socket.EndReceive(sync);
  // ... set up buffer etc. for message receive

 sync = socket.BeginReceive(... MessageReceived, null);
}

private void MessageReceived(IAsyncResult sync) {
  var len = socket.EndReceive(sync);
  // ... process message
}
```

Ultimately putting all the associated in a state object and passing that around (in the completion delegate access via `IAsyncResult.AsyncState`) from BeginReceive can make things easier, but does take a shift from the linear thinking of imperative code and fulling embracing a event driven approach.

---

*2012 Addendum*:

#### .NET 4.5 Version

With the async support in C#5 there is a new option. This uses the compiler to generate the manual continuations (the separate callback methods) and closures (state) from inline code. However there are two things to work around:

1. While `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` has various `…Async` methods these are for the event based asynchronous pattern, not the `Task` based pattern that C#5's `await` uses. Solution: use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to get a single `Task<T>` from  a `Begin…` `End…` pair.
2. `TaskFactory.FromAsync`  only supports passing up to three additional arguments (in addition to the callback and state) to `Begin…`. Solution: a lambda taking zero additional arguments has the right signature, and C# will give us the right closure to pass the arguments in.

Hence (and more fully realised with `Message` being another type that handles the conversion from an initial send of the length encoded in some fixed number of bytes then the content bytes into a length for the content's buffer):

```
private async Task<Message> ReceiveAMessage() {
  var prefix = new byte[Message.PrefixLength];

  var revcLen = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                         (cb, s) => clientSocket.BeginReceive(prefix, 0, prefix.Length, SocketFlags.None, cb, s),
                         ias => clientSocket.EndReceive(ias),
                         null);
  if (revcLen != prefix.Length) { throw new ApplicationException("Failed to receive prefix"); }
  
  int contentLength = Message.GetLengthFromPrefix(prefix);
  var content = new byte[contentLength];
  
  revcLen = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                         (cb, s) => clientSocket.BeginReceive(content, 0, content.Length, SocketFlags.None, cb, s),
                         ias => clientSocket.EndReceive(ias),
                         null);
  if (revcLen != content.Length) { throw new ApplicationException("Failed to receive content"); }
  
  return new Message(content);
}
```

Comment: Did you spot what I was doing wrong? :( Can you tell me how should I improve my current code

Comment: @Manzoo: not directly, which is why I suggested a simpler approach of keeping different operations (message length and message body). Simpler code will be easier to debug.

Comment: @Richard: Can you provide an example which uses state object as you mentioned

Comment: @Manzoo: That would take more time than I have (especially to verify it). Essentially: put all the state (buffers, socket, state flag) into a helper type. Pass that from operation to operation rather than using global state.

Comment: Your updated example is very interesting, but a little difficult to read. Could you be convinced to include comments or supplement with a little more description? I am curious whether this could be the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418613/socket-buffers-the-data-it-receives

Comment: @NielsBrinch I doubt it: this answer is using showing how to convert from separate Begin/End methods into something matching the Task Parallel Library approach that is thus compatible with C#5's async and await. I'm not sure what I would comment if you have an understanding of the APIs I am using and see note #2 above the code.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps what you want to do is chain your call-backs :

pseudo code:

```
// read the first 2 bytes as message length
BeginReceive(msg,0,2,-,-,new AsyncCallback(LengthReceived),-)

LengthReceived(ar) {
  StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
  Socket s = so.workSocket;
  int read = s.EndReceive(ar);
  msg_length = GetLengthFromBytes(so.buffer);
  BeginReceive(so.buffer,0,msg_length,-,-,new AsyncCallback(DataReceived),-)
}

DataReceived(ar) {
  StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
  Socket s = so.workSocket;
  int read = s.EndReceive(ar);
  ProcessMessage(so.buffer);
  BeginReceive(so.buffer,0,2,-,-,new AsyncCallback(LengthReceived),-)
}
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx for correct examples

Answer (score 1):

Usually BeginXXX methods indicate an asynchronous operation, and you seem to want to do it in a synchronous manner.

If indeed you want a synchronous client/server maybe this will help http://sharpoverride.blogspot.com/2009/04/another-tcpip-server-client-well-it.html

Comment: No, I want it asynchronous. Thanks

Comment: Manzoor, you can perform synchronous I/O on another Thread. Much easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It will help if you describe the structure of the message you are sending.

As long as you have only one BeginReceive() outstanding, it will complete and give you the next available bytes of data on the wire. If you have more than one outstanding at the same time, then all bets are off, because .net does not guarantee that the completion will be in any given order.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, don't use global variables here - use a class for socket state.  Something like:

```
public class StateObject
{
    public const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 1024;           //size of receive buffer

    public byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_SIZE];  //receive buffer
    public int dataSize = 0;                        //data size to be received
    public bool dataSizeReceived = false;           //received data size?
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  //received data String
    public int dataRecieved = 0;

    public Socket workSocket = null;                //client socket.
    public DateTime TimeStamp;                      //timestamp of data
} //end class StateObject
```

Before trying to resend the message, you should verify the socket... you might have a socket exception.

You should probably have a return; after your WaitForData call in the "if" block of ReceiveComplete.

Timothy Pratley said it above, one error will be in bytesRecieved the second time through.  Each time you are only measuring the bytesReceived from that EndReceive and then comparing it to messageLength.  You need to keep a sum of all bytesRecieved.

And your biggest error is that in your first call to ReceiveComplete, you take account for the fact that the message might (most likely) contain more data than just the size of the message - it will probably contain half the message as well.  You need to peel off the data size, and then also store the rest of the message in your message variable.